# Where to find resource of Japanese - Chinese dictionary

Tags: nlp, cjk, language-translation, machine-translation

Hey I am trying to provide japanese - chinese translation functionality for my project. I have found [Rikaichan](https://github.com/Kalamandea/Rikaichan) which is a chrome plugin that achieves a popup japanese - english translation. Rikaichan uses some online dictionaries for translation. In the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwVl0WUbZr5QQkpEdV9YS1RYNDg) this project provides there are a lot of dictionaries corresponding to different languges. I am wondering is there a Chinese version of this kind of dictionary? If not is there any online resource for japanese - chinese dictionary data I could retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

I found below links, which could be useful:

https://github.com/himselfv/wakan

https://github.com/fabiencro/knmt

https://github.com/Gnurou/tagainijisho